# What is the best practice for using logs in a multi-services system in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, logging, multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out what is the best way for logging in a multiservice environment in python.
I am using the python logging package and use the FileRotateHandler. I am holding a folder that rotated every day at midnight (log -> log_date). The problem here is race conditions, many processes are trying to rotate the folder at the same time so I must use a lock that hurts the performance.
I was thinking about using MongoDB for logging.
can you suggest a better way for the logging?

Answer (score 0):

Rotate files, not directories. In Unix-derived operating systems log rotation using files is guaranteed to not lose data and not block.

Once the files are rotated, the old file can be moved to a different place including a directory structure you like.